# Eclipse plugin version conflict

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm suffering from the version conflict on Eclipse.

I want to use the following two plugins in one Eclipse instance.

- **org.abc.plugin1a**

  - has a dependency on **org.eclipse.plugin1b_1.0.0**
  - (works well only with version 1.0.0, not work with the newer version!)
  - impossible to be maintained because of a certain reason
- **org.eclipse.plugin2a**

  - has a dependency on **org.eclipse.plugin1b_2.0.0** (or newer)

Actually **org.abc.plugin1a** was developed experimentally by an ex-employee, not by me. The source codes are available but too complicated.
I found there are huge differences between **org.eclipse.plugin1b_1.0.0** and **2.0.0**.
So it is almost impossible for me to update **org.abc.plugin1a** to work with **org.eclipse.plugin1b_2.0.0**

Is there any answer to solve my problem?

Comment: Firstly, I thought that it would be good to install the both versions into one Eclipse and specify `Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.plugin1b_1.0.0;bundle-version="1.0.0"` in `MANIFEST.MF` of **org.abc.plugin1a**. But I found Eclipse loads the latest one only.

Answer (score 0):

Specify both the minimum and maximum version of the plugin in the `Require-Bundle`:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.plugin1b_1.0.0;bundle-version="[1.0.0,1.0.0]"
```

This will not work if plugin `org.eclipse.plugin1b` is marked as a `singleton` since in that case Eclipse will only load one version of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you! Lucky! `org.eclipse.plugin1b` is not a singleton. **But**... I put the old version `org.eclipse.plugin1b_1.0.0` into /eclipse/dropins or /eclipse/plugins/. However, only the new one in /eclipse/plugins are loaded. Should I need do something special for this?